# How can we create partial shipment programmatically using rest api

Tags: shipping, rest-api, magento2.3.3

I am looking to create a partial shipment to manage back order 
here is what I am looking.

Customer place the below items
Item1       qty 5
Item2       qty 10
Item4       qty 8

I wanted to ship the available product and quantity for the initial shipment then ship the reaming second time

here is the product and quantity that I nee to ship initially

Item1       qty 1
Item2       qty 5
Item4       qty 3

here is my model class

```
  <?php


namespace Vendor\Modulename\Model;


use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Vendor\Modulename\Api\Data\ShipmentDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class ShipmentManagement extends AbstractModel implements \Vendor\Modulename\\Api\ShipmentInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $_orderRepository;

    /**
     * @var Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier
     */
    protected $_shipmentNotifier;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order $orderModel
     */
    protected $_convertOrder;

    /**
     * @var Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory
     */
    protected $_trackFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory
     */
    protected $_shipmentFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory
     */
    protected $_transactionFactory;


    protected $_logger;

    /**
     * @var Vendor\Modulename\Model\EsnFactory
     */

    protected $_esnFactory;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\Order $convertOrder,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory $trackFactory,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier $shipmentNotifier,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory $shipmentFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory,
        \Vendor\Modulename\\Model\EsnFactory $esnFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->_orderRepository =   $orderRepository;
        $this->_convertOrder = $convertOrder;
        $this->_trackFactory = $trackFactory;
        $this->_shipmentNotifier = $shipmentNotifier;
        $this->_shipmentFactory = $shipmentFactory;
        $this->_transactionFactory = $transactionFactory;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_esnFactory  =   $esnFactory;

    }

    /**
     * Get Shipping update.
     * @api
     * @param ShipmentDataInterface $shipment
     * @return ShipmentDataInterface|void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function saveNewShipment($shipment)
    {
        try{
            $order  =   $this->_orderRepository->get($shipment->getOrderId());
            if($order->canShip()){
                $data   = array(
                    'carrier_code'=>$shipment->getCarrierCode(),
                    'title'=>$shipment->getCarrierTitle(),
                    'number'=>$shipment->getTrackingNumber()
                );
                $orderShipment  =   $this->prepareShipment($order, $data);
                if ($orderShipment){
                    $order->setIsInProcess(true);
                    $order->addStatusHistoryComment('ITEM SHIPPED', false);
                    $transactionSave =  $this->_transactionFactory->create()->addObject($orderShipment)->addObject($orderShipment->getOrder());
                    $transactionSave->save();
                }
               // return $orderShipment;
            }
        }  catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __($e->getMessage())
            );
        }


    }

    /**
     * @param $order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     * @param $track array
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function prepareShipment($order, $track)
    {
        $shipment = $this->_shipmentFactory->create(
            $order,
            $this->prepareShipmentItems($order),
            $track
        );
        return $shipment->getTotalQty() ? $shipment->register() : false;
    }
    /**
     * @param $order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     * @return array
     */
    protected function prepareShipmentItems($order)
    {
        $items = [];

        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $items[$item->getItemId()] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
        }
        return $items;
    }


}
```

and here is my post data with shipping qty

```
{
    "shipment": {
        "order_id": 123,
                "carrier_code": "DHLNew",
                "carrier_title": "DHL EXPRESS",
                "tracking_number": "TESTDHL12345",
        "items": [
            {
                "sku": "item1",
                "somedata": "somedata",
                "ShippingBoxNumber": "1",
                "Qty": "1"

            },
            {
                "sku": "item2",
                "somedata": "somedata",
                "ShippingBoxNumber": "1",
                "Qty": "5"
            },
            {
                "sku": "item1",
                "somedata": "somedata",
                "ShippingBoxNumber": "1",
                "Qty": "3" 
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

Any help is appropriated